# How to optimize delete from select with 'in' clause in mysql?

Tags: jquery, mysql, optimization

to delete around 90k records from a table contain 100k records I do :

```
 delete from table1 where id in ( select id from table2 ) ;
```

Takes about 30 mins, if I construct the same dynamiclly in some programing language it run in less than a minute.

```
for i in (records to delete) 
        delete from table1 where id = i
```

how to optimize the native mysql query ?

Comment: how many records are there in table2? `id in (tons and tons and tons of ids)` is going to be slow, no matter what you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use a join operation instead of an `IN (subquery)`, and make sure a suitable index (with `id` as the leading column) is available on table1:

```
DELETE t1.*
  FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id
```

---

**EDIT**

I'm not sure why my answer received a downvote. If this is a bad answer, or is unhelpful, then I'd kind of expect a comment as to why this is a bad answer.

This answer is more terse than most of my answers; I suppose I could have explained why a suitable index is necessary for good performance.

OP question was how to "optimize delete" that used a `col IN (subquery)` predicate. I recognize that I failed to provide an explanation as to *why* that pattern can lead to suboptimal performance; and *why* a join operation can sometimes be more efficient. OP asked "how to optimize native sql query"...  the short answer is to re-write the query.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql is bad with IN subqueries,use exists

```
delete from table1 where exists ( select 1 from table2 WHERE table1.id=table2.id ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE 
  table1.*
FROM 
  table1, table2
WHERE 
  table1.id = table2.id
```

or use JOIN.
Avoid IN if at all possible.

Comment: Your example is an implicit `JOIN` which has been deprecated since 1992.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29